# NSFetchedResultsController - How to show the right sections rows in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data, magicalrecord

I have a list of countries and venues read in by JSON.  It now reads in correctly and seems to store relationships.

```
// Read JSON

NSString *jsonPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"venues" ofType:@"json"];

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:jsonPath];

    id json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error - %@", error);
    } else {
        //NSLog(@"JSON = %@", json);


        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
            /*
             "USA": [
             {
             "venue": "Von Braun Center",
             "city" : "Huntsville",
             "state": "Alabama",
             "capacity": 13760
             },
             */

            for (NSDictionary *dict in json) {
                NSString *name = (NSString *) [dict objectForKey:@"name"];
                NSArray *venueList = (NSArray *) [dict valueForKey:@"venues"];



                [MagicalRecord saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *c) {
                    Country *country = [Country createInContext:c];
                    [country setName:name];

                    NSMutableArray *listOfVenues = [NSMutableArray array];

                    NSLog(@"Country - %@", country.name);

                    for (NSDictionary *venueData in venueList) {

                        NSString *name = (NSString *) [venueData objectForKey:@"venue"];
                        NSString *city = (NSString *) [venueData objectForKey:@"city"];
                        NSString *state = (NSString *) [venueData objectForKey:@"state"];
                        //NSNumber *capacity = (NSNumber *) [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[venueData valueForKey:@"capacity"] intValue]];

                        Venue *v = [Venue createInContext:c];
                        [v setName:name];
                        [v setCity:city];
                        [v setState:state];
                        [v setCountry:country];
                        [listOfVenues addObject:v];
                        NSLog(@"Venue - %@, %@", v.name, v.country.name);
                    } // next

                    [country setVenues:[NSSet setWithArray:listOfVenues]];

                } completion:^{
                }];
            } // next

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [[NSManagedObjectContext defaultContext] saveNestedContexts];                
                NSUInteger entities = [Venue countOfEntities];
                NSLog(@"Venues saved = %d", entities);
            });
        });

    } // end if
```

This produces a log of venues, like this;

Loading venue data...

```
Country - USA
Venue - Von Braun Center, USA
Venue - Birmingham Convention Center, USA

Country - UK
Venue - O2 Arena, UK
Venue - MEN Arena, UK
```

So far so good.

But when I get to the actual Venue view it simply displays the venues in alphabetical order but it does displays the section at their correct

My code is;

```
// viewDidLoad
    self.fetchedResultsController = [Venue fetchAllGroupedBy:@"country.name" withPredicate:nil sortedBy:@"name" ascending:YES];

#pragma mark - Table View

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [[[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section] numberOfObjects];

}

-(NSString*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo name];
}

// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tv dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}

- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    Venue *v = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = v.name;
}
```

What this produces on the screen is the following;

I have tried resetting the app and its data to no avail.

Screenshot ([via Imageshack](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/850/ym55.png/))

As you can see, the list is just alphabetical and not correct and not split up across the relevant sections.

It seems to stem from the

```
Venue *v = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

line but I am not sure how to fix it.

I am wondering what I am doing wrong and how I can fix it so that it is displaying the correct data in the correct section.

Comment: Your screenshot looks OK to me. You group by country name and sort by venue name within a section. What's the problem?

Comment: The venues are not in the correct country. IE: American Airlines Arena does not exist in the UK, and should be listed under USA not UK.

Comment: The records are not displaying in the correct group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to put the sections in the right groups (ie: USA venues now belong to the USA country)

```
self.fetchedResultsController = [Venue fetchAllGroupedBy:@"country.name" withPredicate:nil sortedBy:@"country.name" ascending:YES delegate:self inContext:managedObjectContext];
```

But now what is happening is that the venues are not ordered by name ascending.

I get a list like this;

Screenshot:
http://img443.imageshack.us/img443/340/6f3o.png

The venues are now grouped to countries, but the venues themselves are not ordered in A-Z.

I would like my venues to be arranged in A-Z and the countries would not be ordered.

But I am not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

After setting the country for a venue

```
[v setCountry:country];
```

this line is redundant and might break your relationships

```
[country setVenues:[NSSet setWithArray:listOfVenues]];
```

You only have to set the relationship once. The reverse relationship is generated automatically.

Comment: I have now fixed this, I can group the venues; but the venues are not ordered yet

Comment: Great - success!! You should accept the answer. As for ordering, you can order your items once you have retrieved them with `sortedArrayUsingSortDescriptors:`.

Comment: It was just weird because I expected `Venue fetchAllGroupedBy:@"country.name" withPredicate:nil sortedBy:@"name" ascending:YES` to group by country name and sort by the venue name; but it looks like it does not do that; i will try sort descriptors

Comment: You need more than one sort descriptor. The first one should reflect the section name sorting, the next one the items under the section. Still, this is a separate question and you should accept the answer and open a new question if you need to.